# OnSelectedIndexChanged not working within the asp:updatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown in which list of countries will be listed.During the select `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event country code such as +91 will be shown in a textbox. The dropdown should be in `<asp:Update panel>` tag and the update panel just working fine. `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event also working in the code behind. but the problem is the country code value not displayig in the textbox.

Here is my code..

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList 
      runat="server" 
      ID="ddl_country" 
      AutoPostBack="true" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_country_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
      ControlToValidate="ddl_country" 
      ID="reqCountry" 
      ValidationGroup="req" 
      class="validation-msg" 
      ErrorMessage="Please select a country" 
      InitialValue="0" 
      runat="server" 
      Display="Dynamic">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger 
      ControlID="ddl_country" 
      EventName="ddl_country_SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_countrycode"/>
```

Comment: How will your text box update without a postback. It needs to be in an update panel that gets triggered by the DropdownList postback

Comment: put <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_countrycode"/> inside update panel too

Comment: but i want my textboxt out of the update panel bez after dropdown, some of the textboxs will be there in my coding..

Comment: @Selvakesavan but here showing one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text_countrycode is outside any update panel in the code above. So it's in the form and the entire form needs to post back for this to change it's text.

You're probably using Updatepanels because you don't want the entire form to flash and post back.

Changing the dropdown list doesn't refresh the entire page because it's in an Update Panel. If you want the Textbox to be updated without an whole page post back, put it in it's own updatepanel and trigger it from the first one.

Or even easier, just put them together in the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Add Textbox Control Inside the `<ContentTemplate>`.

Try this code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_country" AutoPostBack="true" 
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_country_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="ddl_country" ID="reqCountry"
                                            ValidationGroup="req" class="validation-msg" ErrorMessage="Please select a country"
                                            InitialValue="0" runat="server" Display="Dynamic">
       </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text_countrycode"/>
     </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_country" EventName="ddl_country_SelectedIndexChanged" />
         </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: There won't be any need for a trigger if they're all in the same updatepanel